# DirectSound affects system volume on WinXP

Tags: volume, directsound, waveout

I'm currently developing an audio engine that is used in voice network chat software.
Everything is working fine - capture/playback/mixing channels.

The problem is in using it under Windows XP. I've been getting user reports with information 
that their global system volume is set to zero after launching the application.

I'm assuming that happens because of WaveOut/DSound conflict.

How can I force DSound not to affect system volume?
Playback device is initialized:
  DirectSoundCreate8(&GUID, &pAudio, NULL);

and:

pAudio->SetCooperativeLevel(parentWnd, DSSCL_PRIORITY);

I'm currently not able to debug the application, cause I'm using Vista and everything is OK.

Hope you can help me with this issue!
Thanks a Lot!

Regards,
Anton.

Comment: Hello again,
as far as I understood the problem is that
PRIMARY BUFFER SetVolume method also changes system volume on WinXP. 
How can I force DSound not to effect the XP system volume?!!

Please, help!

Regards, Anton

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you don't just set the volume on the secondary buffers?  Job done!

If you already are setting the volume on the secondary buffers then all you need is a global multiplier to multiplier each volume that gets set on a buffer by.